# Can a class test scores with a bimodal distribution provide statistical evidence for cheating?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, statistical-inference

I know the normal distribution can represent many things in nature. **Most items are normally distributed**. I recently watched a video of a professor who claims that **biomodal distributions provide evidence of cheating**. He states that biomodal distribution "**when external forces are applied to a data set that creates a systematic bias to a data set**" aka cheating. He compares this information to previous grade distributions of students given the same test in other years when he gave the test and estimated that **1/3 of his students have cheated**. My question is **does a bimodal distribution really provide statistical evidence of cheating?** Can't it be that some students do very poorly and some students do really well, leaving a peak that is low and a peak that is high? **Do biomodal distribution really mean there is a higher probability of "when external forces are applied to a data set that creates a systematic bias to a data set?"**

The link to the video is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rbzJTTDO9f4

Yes, I get some students admitted to cheating, but that doesn't answer my question. **My question is can a teacher really provide statistical evidence of someone cheating without them admitting it? I know statistics is all about probability, so can a teacher claim that the probability of this is really lower than a certain threshold and say because of this there exist a statistical significance of them cheating? And how can they approximate 1/3 of there students cheated just by comparing the bimodal distribution to a normal distribution.**

To me, it seems that the teacher is just trying to use scare tactics with his "statistics" and guilt students into admitting to cheating rather than have any evidence of them cheating.

PS: I know cheating is wrong, but I know there must be a lot of innocent students in his class that were also accused of cheating, so that is why I asked this question. (I don't actually go to that university)

Comment: Yes, If a student gets a significantly higher score, he most likely cheated.

Comment: @DeanBearl But how do you know how much is significantly higher enough to make that claim. And also can't the student also study? What if there are students that always get high score, but cheat on every test. Like wise their will also be honest student that get high score and never cheat. Can you explain how statistics is used to prove a student cheating without them admitting it. Is there a certain way of showing the students score rising a certain amount higher is so statically unlikely that it wouldn't happen just by chance

Comment: I don't think so. A non-normal distribution implies that the hypotheses of the Central Limit Theorem are not satisfied. The key hypothesis is that the sources of error are independent. Three sources of variation in the scores are that some students are smarter, some students are better prepared in terms of prerequisites, and some students work harder. The smarter students probably have a better grasp of the prerequisites. Students who generally work harder will have done better in previous courses. Etc - various reasons for variation in the scores are far from independent.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thanks. I knew something was fishy, but didn't have the mathematics to say that the professor is making a huge assumption. The CLT only require a sample size of 30 right? But anyway I like the three sources of variation and agree with them 100%.

Comment: Over the years, I have been struck by the remarkably poor fit of the normal to raw exam scores.  Sometimes the reason is obvious: scheduling constraints can put students from different populations (Electrical Engineering students and Civil Engineering students) in the same class. In exams at my university, students are fairly widely separated, and there is effective monitoring, with limited opportunities for cheating. The only really effective strategy, in a large enough class, is to have someone else write your exam. The situation is very different in the crowded conditions of in-class tests.

Comment: First, most items are NOT normally distributed. Even something as simple (and bounded in range) as human weight is not normally distributed and has a noticeable skew. I watched the beginning of lecture - the the prof claimed that the average grade was 1.5 grades higher than average over the years - and that's sufficient evidence for cheating *en masse* and percentage of students who cheated can be ball-parked from it. However there is NO possible evidence to show that a *particular* student cheated. That's why there is one blank in a firing squad.

Comment: @A.S. I am sorry. I am confused on the CLT. I thought it guaranteed that large samples will be normally distributed, but I guess that is not the case. I guess your right, that if the overall test scores improve by a lot with a large sample it is pretty sketchy. I also get how you can't assume that an individual student cheated. So, I guess he said he knows which student cheated as a scare tactic to make them confess. But he can't have proof that an individual student cheated. He can only say the class as a whole may have some students that cheated. I think I understand it a little better now.

Comment: He has historical data to compare which *somewhat* justifies him claiming that something is *significantly off* - but not necessarily cheating. There are alternative "rare events" explanations - for example a tight, large group of super smart friends decided to take the class together, they studied together and scored significantly higher than the average - creating a second peak. Quite unlikely in a class of $600$, but feasible in smaller classes. Re: CLT - it doesn't talk about distribution of the sample, but distribution of the sample AVERAGE. A test bank is a smoking gun in this case.

Comment: Given overwhelming evidence (statistical and circumstancial) that students cheated en masse, he can construct some kind of a likelihood of cheating based on past student's performance and intangible factors, but it would be pretty bogus and won't stand scrutiny, since academic performance can vary greatly on any scale.

Comment: @A.S. My argument against that is what if the students cheated on past exams too? Then they would always have high scores and you wouldn't be able to distinguish them from a person that has high scores that took all of his/her exams honestly with academic integrity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could be mistaken, but I think that in general, whenever you see something that is too far against the norm, it raises red flags, which may be what he is talking about. Here is a glaring example from standardized testing, where the minimum score to pass this test was 30%: [image: Taken from Reddit, r/dataisbeautiful]

Here is the original reddit post: https://www.reddit.com/r/dataisbeautiful/comments/27dx4q/distribution_of_results_of_the_matura_high_school/

Comment: Yes, I agree! That when data is far away from the normal it throws a red flag. But he claimed 1/3 of his students cheated? How can you make that claim by just looking at the distribution of test scores and comparing it to previous years? How do you come up with the number 1/3? He also claimed that he knew which students cheated purely based on statistics? I agree with the fact that if the grades are very far from normal that you can say that the population as whole may contain some students that cheated? But how do you know how many and which ones without them confessing?